# Help on formulating my (newbie) question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Although I've been programming for over 5 years now (c#, php), I'm still learning about js. More importantly, I want to learn **how** to ask a question properly on Stackoverflow.

Let's take two very similar questions (in my opinion) and analyse them: [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735007) and [hot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889317)

- We both are looking for explanation (why?) something works.
- We both have provided the code in question.
- The questions are very specific and very unlikely to have duplicates.
- **However**, the underlying Javascript concepts definitely have been answered on SO before, but we are not familiar with these js terminologies hence we cannot find the answers.
- If we would study javascript, we would find the answers (long route).
- Instead, we asked help on SO (short route).

Yet, somehow there's a huge difference in votes.

My immediate thoughts are:

1. Fix the title. Ask for explanation of concept instead of "why?".
2. I should have written my own code instead of asking about particular library.

Can you advise please what did I miss in my question? Your feedback would help me to understand how to write better questions in the future.

Comment: As soon as a question goes hot it can't really be compared to anything. I wonder how many votes/views it had when it hit the hot list.

Comment: Sometime simply post a questione in the "right" timeslot change the reaction of SO a lot, but don't ask me what is the "right" timeslot 'cause I don't know it myself

Comment: I've noticed this tendency as well. Being in the right place at the right time. In this case, I was hoping it's more with the quality of the question though.

Comment: @Mark, well the hot question is now closed as a duplicate so they may have won the battle but you won the war ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two salient differences:

1. dotslash's question was a bit clearer. Yours was kind of muddled with datumAnalyzers and so on and went on some tangent that I still don't understand about how it "shouldn't work unless it's nested," and then includes another code sample that does something different. These are all opportunities for readers to get lost.

   I don't think it's bad that your code included the whole original invocation, because you weren't sure which part was relevant, but it does make it a little harder to pick out the relevant bits at a glance.

   On the other hand, dotslash's question consisted of an introduction, a very minimal code sample, the expected result and the actual result and asked why it worked that way — a structure that is easy to follow and makes it very easy to formulate an answer to the question. If you aren't sure how to structure a question, that is a great standby: "Here's a minimal example of what I'm doing, here's what I think it will do, here's what it's actually doing. Please fill in the blank in my knowledge."
2. dotslash's question had a less obvious answer and focused on more of a corner case (how does function hoisting interact with variable declarations?), so more people were probably interested in the answer.